# Gradient of Dot Product $\nabla (\lambda \cdot w)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I am following a derivation in a Control Theory [book](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=P4TKxn7qW5kC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Bryson and Ho,

[image]

[image]

I see a statement like,

$$
- \nabla (\lambda \cdot w) = 
-(\lambda \cdot \nabla) w - \lambda \times (\nabla \times w)
$$

This equation is puzzling because in the Vector Calculus [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities) I've seen so far, there is

$$
\nabla (A \cdot B) = 
(A \cdot \nabla) B + (B \cdot \nabla) A + 
A \times (\nabla \times B) + 
B \times (\nabla \times A)
$$

The expression two above seems a few terms short in that regards.

As far as I can tell from the problem there isn't anything special about $\lambda$ or $w$. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: Oh, bummer! On p. 96 I'm getting the dreaded "Görüntülenmeyen bir sayfaya ulaştınız ya da bu kitap için görüntüleme limitinizi doldurdunuz"...

Comment: I added the screenshots.

Comment: $\boldsymbol \lambda$ is a function of $t$ only, its spatial derivatives are zero.

Comment: Of course.. thanks.